# How to prevent access via URL to controller's method in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like add Javascript/jQuery code to my Rails 3 application that will get data from the server and update the page accordingly.

I thought to use jQuery's `$.get()` method:

```
$.get("/get_data_about_page?page=5", function(data) {
  alert("Returned data: [" + data + "]");
});
```

However, I don't want users to access `get_data_about_page` via URL.

How could I disable such access ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically you can't stop someone from scraping it if they're determined...

You could set a variable in the session when the main page is loaded and then protect the AJAX action so that it only responds if the session variable is set - this would prevent naive use of the URL but it's not foolproof.